# jquery mobile add data-add-back-btn via jquery

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to add a `data-add-back-btn="true"` to a element via jQuery. How can i afhief this?

I've been looking for an option but i haven't been successfull so far.

Perhaps someone here can be of some help.

```
<div data-role="page" id="item" data-add-back-btn="true">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>ProjectName</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">   
    <h1 id="newsTitel"></h1> 
    <p id="newsContent"></p>    
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the block. the button is now hardcoded but I want it to be dynamica added.

Comment: i don't know how to add the data-add-back-btn="true" to the <div> tag with javascript

Comment: @AntonBaksheiev the question is at the end of his text: "this is the block. the button is now hardcoded but I want it to be dynamica added"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you will need to add **addBackBtn** to jQuery Mobile's initialization event, like this:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn=true;
});
```

Comment: would this work:

if (device.platform == 'Android') {
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn=false;
}else{
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn=true;
};

Comment: you're creating a PhoneGap application, right? that should work just fine then

Comment: yes, im useing phonegap. the back buttons should show on ios but not on android